# What does your boss ask your references you put on your application?

Tags: interviewing, hiring-process, references

I took a test for a job, and got a 76%.The job is an entry level tutoring position for high school or college students. The test is a process for hiring people for a job. You have to pass the test in order to do the interview.  I am embarrassed about my test results because this test is in my field of study in college.I got accepted to the interview. During my interview, my boss ask what happened during my test. I told my boss I get bad test anxiety, and he seem to understand. After the interview, I have to fill out an application, and in my application, I have to put three references from university professors. I am very concerned my boss will bring up my test results to my references(which are my professors). My main question is what do your managers ask your professors if the job you applied to is a tutoring position if they contact your professors? Moreover, do you think my boss will talk about my test results to my professors?

Comment: Why would your boss tell the professors your score? Why would that matter? Does your college have a bizarre "if you get 76% on an external application you have to win the collegelimpics or get expelled by the crusty old dean?

Comment: Just hang loose, there's nothing you can change now. Whatever is asked will be asked and we have no idea what your new boss would find appropriate to ask.

Comment: Hello there, I'm afraid that what you ask is off-topic for this site, as what would **our** bosses/managers ask **our** professors will be different for each person that answers, and that would also be company-specific, and quite broad... please [take the tour](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/tour) and check [how to ask](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) so you get to know your way around here :) Welcome to The Workplace. After you do that, please [edit](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/posts/161147/edit) your post so it's not closed.

Comment: This seems as an intrapersonal issue that you extrapolate on others. Chill, nothing you think about will happen. No one have time to do such things. And on proffesional note: if there is some test and you THINK (becasue in reality you might not) you done not so well you might ask if you can go through the bad answers. It will show you want to improve  and learn from your mistakes.

Comment: What would be the problem if the boss tells the profs? Also, if the boss asks them for references, wouldn't that mean the 76% is still okay for the job?

Answer (score 4):

Nobody here can say for certain what they will ask.  It is almost certain that they will just ask how long you worked there and what your position was.  In some jurisdictions your references aren't permitted to give more information than that.

While extremely unlikely in my opinion it's possible they will say something like "user did badly on our test and claims they got test anxiety, do you think they often get test anxiety?".  In that case why would someone who knows you well enough to be used as a reference suddenly alter their opinion of you based on a single comment from someone they don't know at all?  I think your reputation is safe regardless of what the interviewer might say.